# How does one appeal a close decision due to supposed question duplicate?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons, exact-duplicates

[How do I 'share' a folder to the public in dropbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/256845/how-do-i-share-a-folder-to-the-public-in-dropbox)

This isn't my question and I fully agree that my answer isn't the best one, but it is very clear to me that @Sathya is incorrect in his judgment that the question is duplicated.

How does one appeal or contest this? @Sathya's answer is the highest voted accepted one on his duplicate suggestion, and that makes me think he got a little close-happy without reading fully into the question that was asked.

Comment: *I respect and agree with @Sathya's decision*, he closed it because the questions are duplicates "in spirit".  Sathya has demonstrated that he knows Dropbox very well, and if anyone, he can tell whether or not it is a duplicate.

Comment: (inb4 anyone jumps, I was not the one who put in the downvote. It's a perfectly reasonable question )

Comment: I can fully attest to @Sathya's intentions, and he's not a close happy individual.  He has the site best interest in full view at all times.  To be honest This is my fault as I didn't do the proper research to see if the answer was already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can share a single file to the public via a link on dropbox, but what if I have an entire folder that I want to be able to grant access to the public? Is there a way to do this?
>   Is there a way to get this link from Dropbox when I'm on Windows (or via the Web) without creating a public shared folder?

This looks like a single question right? Well (mouseover on the below block)

> the above lines are a combined question of the question marked as closed and the duplicate question.

Since you've posted here - that's one way of appealing. The other way is to flag the question and mention why it should be opened. Alternatively - 5+ 3k users can vote to reopen the question.

My accepted answer on the other one is what prompted me to close it - because the question by indicates that he wants to do the **exact same thing**. Feel free to edit the question to make it look distinct and me/other mods/community can rethink about reopening.

Comment: So kudos on your dramatic presentation, but when I first read it I thought it conflicted.  The first two sentences clearly ask how to create a public folder.  The second sentence clearly asks how to do something *without having* to create a public folder.

Comment: Wow, just realized this is 4 years old.  That's what I get for browsing the sidebar :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson :)